# Repeating a list

Tags: lambda, prolog

Say I need a predicate rep(*?List*, *?Times*, *?TList*) which is true iff *List* is repeated *Times* times in *TList* (for example, `rep([a,c],2,[a,c,a,c])`). It should work as long as two of the arguments are instantiated. Here a somewhat working version:

```
rep(_,0,[]).
rep(List,1,List).
rep(List,Times,TList) :- integer(Times), Times>1,
    succ(RemTimes,Times), append(List,RemList,TList),
    rep(List,RemTimes,RemList).
rep(List,Times,TList) :- var(Times),
    append(List,RemList,TList),
    rep(List,RemTimes,RemList), !,
    succ(RemTimes,Times).
```

Two questions:

1. Isn't there some built-in (that I am unable to find) that does that?
2. Is there a more straight-forward way of doing this? Like getting rid of the last clause? It is necessary because I couldn't find a way to express the relationship between *Times* and *RemTimes* when *Times* is not instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about a specialized builtin. Here a procedure using the generative capability of [length](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2)/2

```
rep(List, Times, TList) :-
    ( var(Times) ; Times > 0 ),  % after joel76' comment...
    ( var(List) ; is_list(List) ), % after false' comment...
    ( var(TList) ; is_list(TList) ), % idem...
    length(List, LA), LA > 0,
    length(TList, LT), LT > 0,
    Times is LT / LA,
    findall(List, between(1, Times, _), [List|Ls]),
    append([List|Ls], TList), !.
```

the final cut avoid looping when any list is free.

Comment: Doesn't work when Times is negative (I agree that it means nothing in the context).

Comment: rep(L,N,[a,c,a,c]). gives L = [a], N = 4.

Comment: It is exactly what I was aiming at. I didn't realize I could use findall in this manner.

Comment: @Boris - note the peculiar pattern [List|Ls] as `result` of findall. That forces the binding when List is free, it's required because findall/3 *copies* the terms handed out to it...

Comment: `rep([1],1,[1,1|_])` loops. **That** is within the spec.

Answer (score 1):

You use SWI-Prolog, so you can do that :

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

rep(Lst, N, R) :-
    (   numlist(1,N, NL)
    ->  foldl(\_X^Y^Z^append(Y, Lst, Z), NL, [], R)
    ;   R = []).
```

To solve CapelliC's remark, **doesn't report X binding on rep(X,2,[a,b,a,b])**
you must write

```
foldl(Lst +\_X^Y^Z^append(Y, Lst, Z), NL, [], R)
```

[Edit] Thanks @false ! Interesting is

```
rep(Lst, N, R) :-
    (   nonvar(N)
    ->  length(NL, N),
        foldl(Lst +\_^Y^append(Y, Lst), NL, [], R)
    ;   foldl(Lst +\_^Y^append(Y, Lst), NL, [], R),
        length(NL, N)),
    !.
```

But unfortunately, it loops with rep([a,b], N, [a,c,a,c]) !

Comment: give error on `rep([a,b],X,[a,b,a,b])` and doesn't report X binding on `rep(X,2,[a,b,a,b])`

Comment: I am not sure I understand... my SWI-Prolog cannot find such a library, nor can I find it documented on the SWI-Prolog web page!

Comment: @Boris: I think you should get [lambda.pl](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) from Ulrich site. AFAIK it's not in SWI library

Comment: +1. You can shorten the lambda with partial application: `foldl(Lst +\_^Y^append(Y, Lst), NL, [], R)`

Answer (score 0):

A simple (but maybe inefficient) strategy is to scan the second list and check each time if the first one is a sublist of the remaining part.

To do the check you could use the [`prefix/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/lists.html%27%29%29) operator from SWI-Prolog.

```
sublist_count(L, R, Times) :-
    sublist_count(L, R, 0, Times).
sublist_count(L, [], Times, Times).
sublist_count(L, [R | Tail], Times, End) :-
    prefix(L, [R | Tail]), !,
    NewTimes is Times + 1,
    sublist_count(L, Tail, NewTimes, End).
sublist_count(L, [R | Tail], Times, End) :-
    sublist_count(L, Tail, Times, End).
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the following make sense. (I'm not handling the case where `Times` is undefined.)

```
rep(List, Times, TList) :-
    length(List, ListLen),
    PrefixLen is ListLen * Times,
    open_list(List, OpenList, OpenList),
    length(TList, PrefixLen),
    append(TList, _, OpenList).
```

where `open_list/3` is defined as:

```
open_list([], X, X).
open_list([H | T1], [H | T2], X) :-
    open_list(T1, T2, X).
```

The idea is to create an infinite list and then cut the required prefix off.

Usage example:

```
?- rep([a, c], 2, TList).
TList = [a, c, a, c].

?- rep(List, 2, TList).
List = TList, TList = [] ;
List = [_G886],
TList = [_G886, _G886] ;
List = [_G886, _G889],
TList = [_G886, _G889, _G886, _G889] ;
```

Comment: It is exaclty the case where Times is undefined that created the initial problem. Without it is not really a pure predicate....